# JQuery show a div for 4 seconds, then hide it and show a different one for 1.4 seconds, and finally the first one with some text in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project that requires showing a grey screen to show images from an array. How can this be done using javascript?

I have tried using  `setinterval` like so:

```
document.getElementById("startStimulation").addEventListener("click", startStimulation);
var images = [];
images[0] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/carretera.jpeg';
images[1] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/ciudad.jpg';
images[2] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/ciudad.jpg';
images[3] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/construccion.jpeg';
images[4] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/fabrica.jpg';
images[5] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/terreno.jpg';

function startStimulation() {
    var current = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var firstInnerInterval = setInterval(function () {
            $('#text').text('');
            $('#flip').hide();
            $('#text').show();
        }, 4000);
        var secondInnerInterval = setInterval(function () {
            $('#text').hide();
            $('#flip').attr('src', images[current]);
            $('#flip').show();
        }, 1400);
        var thirdInnerInterval = setInterval(function () {
            $('#flip').hide();
            $('#text').text(someVariable);
            $('#text').show();
        }, 4000);
        if (current < images.length - 1) {
            current = current + 1;
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 9400);

}
```

But the output is not the desired. HOw can i achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you desire?

```js
document.getElementById("startStimulation").addEventListener("click", startStimulation);
var images = [];
images[0] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/carretera.jpeg';
images[1] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/ciudad.jpg';
images[2] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/ciudad.jpg';
images[3] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/construccion.jpeg';
images[4] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/fabrica.jpg';
images[5] = 'resources/mentalImg/img/terreno.jpg';

var current = 0;

var text = $('#text');
var flip = $('#flip');
var both = text.add(flip);

function startStimulation() {

  text.text('');
  flip.hide();

  setTimeout(function() {
    both.toggle();
    flip.attr('src', images[current]);
  }, 4000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    both.toggle();
    text.text("Some randowm text");
  }, 5400);

  setTimeout(function() {
    if (current < images.length - 1) {
      current++;
      startStimulation();
    }
  }, 9400)
}
```

```css
#text {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#flip {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
<img id="flip">

<button id="startStimulation">Start</button>
```

Comment: Not really. I think it does not stay blank for 4 seconds, then 1.4 seconds of the 1st image, then 4 seconds blank (but with the text which i have not added but that is not my main concern right now).
Then 4 seconds blank again, 1.4 seconds of the seconde image... and so on. It does some weird blinking and i think that the times are not right.

Comment: @ÁngelCáceresLicona I am sorry for earlier. I have updated the code. It seems to be working fine now. Please have a look.